# В чем отличие миксинов от шаблоных селекторов SASS?

Tags: html, css, frontend, sass, scss

Подскажите правильно ли я понял, что отличие миксинов от шаблонных классов в Sass заключается только в том, что в миксин можно передать параметр. Т.е. нет необходимости использовать миксин если ты не собираешься передавать что-то в виде параметра и в таком случае лучше использовать шаблонный класс?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почти, миксин это просто кусок кода. В нем может содержаться и 5 селекторв, а может ни одного. Так же для миксинов доступны переменные и блоки @content. А шаблонный селектор это просто кусок кода, который вы можете переиспользовать несколько раз.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А можете привести пример какой-нибудь, где в миксине несколько селекторов? И насчет этого "Так же для миксинов доступны переменные и блоки @include." Разве нельзя в шаблонном селекторе тоже использовать переменные? Или вы имели ввиду передаваемые параметры?

Comment: @ДмитрийГаврилов перепутал, не include, content. [Вот дока на русском](https://sass-scss.ru/documentation/) там всё очень подробно описано.